# Why does my Kingdoms of Amalur take so long to load?

Tags: pc, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I recently installed a fresh copy of Kingdoms of Amalur on my i7-2600k, 16 gb Win 7 Pro machine through Steam.

After looking through the settings I hit new game and was able to preview almost every game clue before I gave up trying to get the game to do something other than "Loading"

My ATI drivers are up to date and KoA is installed to my SSD.

The game menus are fairly responsive and I don't see any hints why this might happen.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That is surprising on an SSD. Just to rule it out, I'll mention the two things that have gotten me with other games in the past: Are you either downloading a large file at a high transfer rate (such as preloading ME3) or have a weekly data backup running? Basically, a heavy amount of disk i/o has been a culprit for me once or twice.

Comment: No, the only program that was running was KoA with Steam.

Comment: Can you try validating the local game cache to check if all the data is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the the graphics settings and turn off vsync.

For some reason, possibly a bug, this setting can cause the game to have long load times.  It seems that SSD installations are particularly susceptible.